# I deployed a container with a non HTTP worker script to Google Cloud Run and it stops working after 20 minutes all the time

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm deploying a dockerized worker script to Google Cloud Run that is not serving HTTP requests (thus, not an API). I had this exact same image deployed to a fly.io shared CPU that has 1 GB ram and 1 CPU and it has been running smoothly for 3 months straight but in Google Cloud Run the application randomly stops after 20 minutes, there are no error logs and no signs of resource overload (I have 2 CPUs and 2 GB RAM, basically the double of resources I had before).

Everytime before it stops there's a small spike in my resource usage but I don't think it's big enough to make the whole application hang, and as I said before I have absolutely no errors printed in my logs so I don't know what's going on, can I get some guidance? This is my first time deploying in GCloud and there's probably something I'm missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faced the same issue, you have to set the "minimum number of instances" to 1 instead of 0 so it doesn't stop.